# Checking if a driver is loaded for a device

Tags: macos, mac, usb, driver

I'm trying to get a Hauppauge Nova-T USB dongle working under OS X El Capitan. I found an [unofficial driver installer](http://defyne.org/dvb/driver.html) and a [program](http://defyne.org/dvb/iTele.html) to watch television using this dongle, but the program is not detecting it.

In Windows, I know I can go to Device Manager to check if a driver has been loaded for a certain device. How can I verify if a driver was loaded? I've already verified that the dongle was detected using `ioreg -p IOUSB`:

```
+-o Nova-T Stick@14100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x10001c71e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 11>
```

Answer (score 1):

List all loaded drivers:

```
sudo kextstat
```

You may also use it with grep like `sudo kextstat |grep defyne`