# Graphics tablet used to work without a third-party driver. How to reenable this?

Tags: macos

I am using a [Gaomon S620](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R77SNX9) graphics tablet and running macOS Catalina version 10.15.6, although my question doesn't, I think, depend on my specific tablet/OS version.

It used to be the case (before Mojave I think?) that you could plug a graphics tablet into a mac and it would immediately work fine with literally no driver installed. (No fine pressure control or whatever, but I don't need this.) Now I'm guessing that to due some added security restrictions, when I plug in my graphics tablet without downloading Gaomon's driver, my computer recognizes pen movement (the cursor moves), but I am unable to click on anything.

I say that my specific model doesn't matter because many people have had this problem with different tablets:
https://www.reddit.com/r/wacom/comments/9003e4/intuos_pro_my_tablet_pen_hovers_just_fine_but/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wacom/comments/a62n30/tap_to_click_not_working_on_intuos_pro/
https://www.gaomon.net/question/macos_mojave_catalina_solution.html

I know how to solve this issue if I have Gaomon's driver downloaded. Go to Security and Privacy --> Accessibility, etc.

(Basically follow the steps [here](https://machollywood.com/blogs/news/wacom-pen-and-touch-not-working-after-mac-os-mojave-10-14-5-update) and give your third-party driver access to your computer.)

**But I want to use my graphics tablet without installing a third-party driver. Is there a way to reenable this functionality?**

For reference, I am having problems with lag, and I want to check whether it is my driver's fault or if it is just due to high CPU usage. But I can't check because I can't use my graphics tablet anymore without the third-party driver.

**Edit:** To clarify, I never experience lag (whether the Gaomon third-party driver is installed or not) when just moving the cursor. Lag only occurs when I press down and draw. But as stated above, I can only draw when the third-party driver is installed, as otherwise it doesn't recognize clicks.

Comment: To be clear, you don’t want the drivers the manufacturer recommends? https://www.gaomon.net/question/macos_mojave_catalina_solution.html

Comment: @bmike That is correct; see the last paragraph above. Gaomon [suggests](https://www.gaomon.net/question/cursor_delaylag.html#:~:text=Too%20high%20CPU%20usages%20will,your%20tablet%20to%20another%20computer%3A&text=If%20it%20did%20not%20delay,drawing%20program%20and%20your%20computer.) trying to use your tablet without the driver to see if lag is their driver's fault or not.

Comment: Yeah. You’ll want a clean OS on an external device to eliminate your settings for lag.

Comment: It is crazy one needs to give total control over the system for a tablet driver. I hope macOS will offer some API to work with tablets without this. Is there any known tablet to work on latest macOS without any driver? Or at least without total control?

Answer (score 2):

First, try adding the software you are using with the Tablet to **Accessibility**. Next, [try to determine what is the default driver](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224931/checking-if-a-driver-is-loaded-for-a-device) used by Catalina for your Tablet, and add that too (if possible) to **Accessibility**.

While this issue is most probably due to architectural changes in Catalina, try [disabling "System Integrity Protection"](https://fulltip.net/disable-sip-system-integrity-protection-on-macos-catalina-10-15.html) (SIP) and see if it works:

> 1. Go into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities -> Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.

**Be sure to enable it again** after you are done testing, following the same steps as above but using the command `csrutil enable`, once you are done testing.

You can use [Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac) to detect if high CPU is happening when you are using the Tablet.

(Otherwise, inform the manufacturer of the tablet that you can't test what they are asking you to do because of macOS Catalina. You shouldn't need to jump through hoops for something they should be doing to ensure the product works as described on macOS, i.e. they should be the one testing the products thoroughly for mac.)

Comment: I would caution that disabling SIP is quite extreme to get a USB device working. I agree, press the vendor for adequate drivers that don’t compromise your security or stability. Good call on basic permissions in the Security and Privacy pane.

Comment: I like your first suggestion of giving permissions to the default driver. I am having a hard time finding it though. I was able to get a list of all loaded drivers using `sudo kextstat` per the link you gave. However, this returns a list with about 240 items, and it isn't clear which is the default driver. I wonder if there is anyway to check what drivers a USB device is interacting with?

Comment: @bmike I agree, but OP mentioned that they just want to test out first without installing the recommended drivers, and do plan to install the drivers later. Disabling SIP temporarily to test out something should be fine if one is careful.

Comment: @kanso37 I too couldn't find info on how to find the exact driver being used on a mac. System Report (Apple > About this mac > System Report) has a section on USB under "Hardwares" that displays info on the USB devices connected. Perhaps that willl help with your investigation. If not, suggest you make a separate post asking help to determine the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I would bite the bullet and install the drivers. Once you’re sure your hardware and cables work you could try removing them.

- https://www.gaomon.net/question/macos_mojave_catalina_solution.html

Comment: I can get the graphics tablet working just fine with my third-party Gaomon driver installed, and the link you provided is one I gave in my question itself (third link even though it looks different--it goes to the same page). I want it to work without using a third-party driver, like it used to before Mojave. I'm assuming Apple added some sort of system-level restriction that prevents me from being able to click using my graphics tablet, despite the fact that it recognizes cursor movement.

Comment: I’m assuming the cable or pad are broken. Feel free to ignore my advice. You could also install an os externally and install the drivers there if you don’t trust the drivers. This is how I troubleshoot our tablets at work. Test them on the full setup then return the tablet to the user who doesn’t want to make OS changes. I get why people don’t want to change their setup, so I make it easy to do a controlled test with proper drivers. I wouldn’t run this driver on my setup, personally at all.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this has anything to do with my graphics tablet being broken. It used to work without any third-party driver in previous OS versions. Furthermore, see the links above about other people having the exact same problem. I guess installing another operating system is something I can try, but this is a massive pain and only something I would want to do as a last resort (if even). I am hoping that some permissions might be changeable to reenable this functionality, since clearly it at least recognizes my graphics as a mouse, just no taps work.

Comment: @kanso37 I hope it’s easy too, I look forward to someone smarter or more experienced in this than I to answer more narrowly. Reverse engineering all the changes in device handling the last 4 OS versions is a ton of work. How far back OS do you know your specific hardware works out of the box?

Comment: I believe it worked in High Sierra, but to be honest I'm not 100% sure because I'm really bad about updating my computer :/    I realize this question might be a long shot, but I still appreciate your suggestion of trying another OS--it might come down to that.

Comment: +1 on the question. I don’t doubt your request is well thought out and sincere. I keep old installers to test things when we really need to, but as you mention, it takes time that is precious.